# How to use behavioursubject to change parameters in service function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello i am trying to implement behaviour subject to change data in datatable component based on which button is clicked in home component and cant figure it out its really confusing.

So i have service function which gets data from api with two parameters and with click on a button in home component i want to change the parameters of the service so the datatable component info update with the new parameters
this is service

```
export class WeatherService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getWeatherData(
    lat: string = '51.51',     //these are default parameters for london
    lon: string = '-0.13'   //i want to change these with click from home component 
  ): Observable<WeatherData> {
    return this.http.get<WeatherData>(
      `https://archive-api.open-meteo.com/v1/era5?latitude=${lat}&longitude=${lon}&start_date=2005-08-25&end_date=2005-08-25&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,dewpoint_2m,apparent_temperature,surface_pressure,precipitation,rain,cloudcover,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m,soil_temperature_0_to_7cm`
    );
  }
}
```

the service is used here with the default service parameters but want to change the parameters based on the City button clicked on home page

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.weatherDataLoading = true;
    this.weatherService      
      .getWeatherData()     //service is used here with default parameters (lat,long for london)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => (this.weatherDataLoading = false)),
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (historicalWeatherData) => { ...code
```

this is home component with the buttons and each route to weather data component and each should pass new parameters (lat,long) to the service when clicked

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data">London</button>
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data">New York</button>
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data">Tokyo</button>
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data">Sydney</button>
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data">Madrid</button>
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data">Paris</button>
  </div>
```

so when i click on Tokyo for example in home button it redirects me to the weather datatable component and change the lat and long in the service so accurate data is shown for Tokyo and not the default lat and long parameters for London

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involves

- A `BehaviorSubject` which emits the coordinates of the currently selected location (or `null` if there isn't one). Initial value is `null`
- A subscription to the output of this subject which then triggers the `weatherService.getWeatherData` request. This subscription lives inside the `weather-data.component.ts`
- Click events (buttons) originating from your `home.component` which emit coordinate values from your `BehaviorSubject` when clicked

`weather.model.ts`

```
export interface ICoordinates {
  lat: number;
  lon: number;
}
```

`weather.service.ts`

```
coordinatesSubject: BehaviourSubject<ICoordinates | null> = new BehaviorSubject<ICoordinates | null>(null);

getWeatherData$(
  lat: string = '51.51',     //these are default parameters for london
  lon: string = '-0.13'   //i want to change these with click from home component 
): Observable<WeatherData> {
  return this.http.get<WeatherData>(
    `https://archive-api.open-meteo.com/v1/era5?latitude=${lat}&longitude=${lon}&start_date=2005-08-25&end_date=2005-08-25&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,dewpoint_2m,apparent_temperature,surface_pressure,precipitation,rain,cloudcover,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m,soil_temperature_0_to_7cm`
  );
}
```

`weather-data.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.watchForCoordinatesChanges();
}

watchForCoordinatesChanges(): void {
  this.weatherService.coordinatesSubject
    .asObservable()
    .subscribe({
      next: (coordinates: Coordinates | null) => {
        this.getWeatherData(coordinates)
      }
    })
}

getWeatherData(coordinates: Coordinates | null): void {
  const weatherData$: Observable<WeatherData> =
    coordinates
      ? this.weatherService.getWeatherData$(coordinates.lat, coordinates.long)
      : this.weatherService.getWeatherData$();

  const weatherDataWithLoader$: Observable<WeatherData> =
    defer(
      () => {
        this.weatherDataLoading = true;

        return weatherData$
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => { this.weatherDataLoading = false }),
            takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
          )
        }
    )

  weatherDataWithLoader$
    .subscribe({
        next: (historicalWeatherData: WeatherData) => { // ...code }
    })
}
```

`home.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data" (click)="weatherService.coordinatesSubject.next({lat: 123, lon: 123})">London</button>
    <button pButton type="button" routerLink="/weather-data" (click)="weatherService.coordinatesSubject.next({lat: 456, lon: 456})">New York</button>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Depending on your use case and what you are doing with the data, this could be improved further

Comment: this is very helpful thank you very much but yeah with behavioursubject it would be awesome :)

Comment: also please note that home component and weather data component are separate components and dont have parent-child relationship

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I misread the question and didn't appreciate the different components being used. I have updated my answer to hopefully be more in line with what you were after (and make use of a BehaviorSubject to handle coordinate state).